# Is there a good way to determine whether a Steam Key has been used without redeeming it?

Tags: product-key, steam

Long story short, I had a brief period where I signed up for just about every software bundle I could because I got caught up in collecting the games. The Humble Bundles work nicely in that they indicate which keys have been redeemed and which have not, but some of the other bundles don't do this. If I have a list of keys, and I have my Steam credentials, is there any good way to automate the process of determining if

1. I already own the game
2. Or I've already posted the key on Facebook and someone has claimed it

Answer (score 2):

There is no system to determine if you have used a key or not.

You can attempt to use the key and it will either add the game to your account or tell you that you already own that product.